# dictionary insert default value if empty

Tags: python, dictionary, key, default-value, is-empty

I'm creating a dictionary from a xml file as follows:

```
for edge in root.findall('n:graph/n:edge', ns):
        source = edge.get('source')
        target = edge.get('target')
        edges[(source, target)] = tuple([data.text for data in edge if \
        (data.get('key') == keys[0] or data.get('key') == keys[1])])
```

Which gives me an output like this one:

> { ( '4893468839', '977369380' ) : ( 'name', ' length') ... }

Is there a way I can put a default text 'noName' when the values for the field **name** is empty? All the keys have a length value but not all of then have a name one so I want to avoid an output like:

> { ( '4893468839', '977369380' ) : ( ' length' , ) ... }

To get something like this in that case:

> { ( '4893468839', '977369380' ) : ( 'noName' , ' length' ) ... }

More detailed information:

```
from lxml import etree
    class graph():
        _path = ""
    def _readFile(self):
            data = etree.parse(self._path)
            root = data.getroot()
    for edge in root.findall('n:graph/n:edge', ns):
                source = edge.get('source')
                target = edge.get('target')
                edges[(source, target)] = tuple([data.text for data in edge if data.get('key') in keys[:2]])
```

Given a piece of xml like the following:

```
<key attr.name="ref" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d14" />
<key attr.name="name" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d13" />
<key attr.name="geometry" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d12" />
<key attr.name="length" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d11" />
<key attr.name="oneway" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d10" />
<key attr.name="highway" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d9" />
<key attr.name="bridge" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d8" />
<key attr.name="osmid" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d7" />

<edge id="0" source="4331489627" target="4331489577">
  <data key="d7">435211336</data>
  <data key="d13">Calle Carretera</data>
  <data key="d9">residential</data>
  <data key="d10">False</data>
  <data key="d11">52.45</data>
  <data key="d12">LINESTRING (-4.8413613 39.4799045, -4.8414814 39.4798489, -4.8419449 39.4797838)</data>
</edge>
```

Will generate the following output im okay with:

> { ( '4331489627', '4331489577' ) : ( 'Calle Carretera', ' 52.45') }

But for example there are some edges, mising the name or d13 key tag like this one:

```
<edge id="0" source="982621562" target="946409159">
      <data key="d7">483537143</data>
      <data key="d14">CM-4106</data>
      <data key="d9">secondary</data>
      <data key="d10">False</data>
      <data key="d11">104.66499999999999</data>
      <data key="d12">LINESTRING (-4.8366071 39.4783468, -4.8368979 39.4789602, -4.8371678 39.4791592)</data>
    </edge>
```

In those cases, im getting this output since the tag text is not found:

> { ( '982621562', '946409159' ) : (' 52.45', ) }

And if possible, would want to get something like:

> { ( '982621562', '946409159' ) : ( 'noName', ' 52.45') }

Comment: did you try anything like `data.text or 'noName' for data in edge if data.get('key') in keys[:2]`?

Comment: @SamMason have just tried but seems to do the same I had without printing the default value. The edges have several keys but some of them are missing it and is in that case where I want to put the default value

Comment: could you post a more complete example?  for example, include some xml that exhibits the issue, packages imports, presumably a call like `ET.fromstring(data)` and so on

Comment: @SamMason sure, i have edited the post with more detailed info. thanks for your time.

Comment: ah, that's not what you posted before!  you've got a comma for missing data in a different place which indicates something completely different going on.  please copy/paste output directly as little differences like that are important and provide information about what is going on

Comment: you are right, thought it wouldn't make much more difference. im quite new to python, my bad.

Comment: no probs, all part of the learning experience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the above, I've put together an example that actually works:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring("""
<xml><graph>
<key attr.name="ref" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d14" />
<key attr.name="name" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d13" />
<key attr.name="geometry" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d12" />
<key attr.name="length" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d11" />
<key attr.name="oneway" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d10" />
<key attr.name="highway" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d9" />
<key attr.name="bridge" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d8" />
<key attr.name="osmid" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="d7" />
<edge id="0" source="4331489627" target="4331489577">
  <data key="d7">435211336</data>
  <data key="d13">Calle Carretera</data>
  <data key="d9">residential</data>
  <data key="d10">False</data>
  <data key="d11">52.45</data>
  <data key="d12">LINESTRING (-4.8413613 39.4799045, -4.8414814 39.4798489, -4.8419449 39.4797838)</data>
</edge>
<edge id="0" source="982621562" target="946409159">
  <data key="d7">483537143</data>
  <data key="d14">CM-4106</data>
  <data key="d9">secondary</data>
  <data key="d10">False</data>
  <data key="d11">104.66499999999999</data>
  <data key="d12">LINESTRING (-4.8366071 39.4783468, -4.8368979 39.4789602, -4.8371678 39.4791592)</data>
</edge>
</graph></xml>
""")

keys = {}
for key in root.findall('graph/key'):
  keys[key.get('attr.name')] = key.get('id')

key_name = keys['name']
key_length = keys['length']

out = {}
for edge in root.findall('graph/edge'):
  data = dict((d.get('key'), d.text) for d in edge.findall('data'))
  value = (data.get(key_name, 'noName'), data[key_length])
  out[(edge.get('source'), edge.get('target'))] = value

print(out)
```

note that you get a `None` for the second edge now.  before it was "missing" because you were telling it to be filtered out.  instead, my code creates a dictionary based on the xml and then always populates the values in `out` with tuples containing two elements.

Comment: thank you very much! have already solved it by creating that 'aux' dict to store all key values and then getting the info to put it in the other one. have a problem do, in my code i was filtering cause depending of the xml file im parsing, the d13 could be another key, d12 for example so i was creating a list by reading the begging of the file to look for those keys with attr.name="name" or length that is the one im interested in

Comment: is there any way of doing something similar? now i get the output i want but just for those files where d13 and d11 are the keys, but they may change. in the main post i have added the xml part where the 'index' of keys is with the attr.names i was talking about

Comment: cheers man, thank u very much for your help, much appreciated! :D ps: have just realised there are two keys called 'name' i guess ill have to figure out a way to differentiate them haha

Comment: have stored also the 'for' attribute in each key of the dict to then look for them as  key_name = keys[('name', 'edge')], avoiding the other name tag which is for graphs.